# get Jquery mobile checkbox group value in php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkboxlist

I want to get the value of checkbox group in Jquery mobile application in php code 
jQuery mobile code (I found sample example on this jQuery mobile checkbox group on this link
http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2yjgg/)

```
    <div data-role="page" id="attend" >
<p>Choose Student who attende:</p>
<div id='group_checkboxes'></div>
<form method="post"  action="sign_up3.php"  target="_new" >
<script>
$("#attend").live("pageinit",function(event){

 var checkboxes = '';
 for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
checkboxes += '<input type="checkbox" id="foo' + i + '" class="custom" name="attend_list[]" /><label for="foo' + i + '">Foo checkbox' + i + '</label>';
  }
     var controlgroup = $("<fieldset/>", {"data-role": "controlgroup"}).append(checkboxes);
     $("#group_checkboxes").append(controlgroup.controlgroup());
     $("[type=checkbox]").checkboxradio();
     $("[data-role=controlgroup]").controlgroup("refresh");
  });                     

 </script>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" >

  </form>
</div>
```

php code

```
<?php

  foreach($_POST['attend_list'] as $value)
    {
     echo $value ;
    }

  ?>
```

but when submit php code show this error

"Notice: Undefined index: attend_list in C:\xampp\htdocs\att\sign_up3.php on line 3

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\att\sign_up3.php on line 3 "

Comment: I found it in this link
http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2yjgg/

Answer (score 0):

Move this:

```
<div id='group_checkboxes'></div>
```

Into the form.  I.E. after this line:

```
<form method="post"  action="sign_up3.php"  target="_new" >
```

The way it is currently written the checkbox elements are not included in the form, so when it submits, their data is not passed along with the form submission.